# problem with progress bar problem with NumUpDown box

Tags: c#, winforms, numbers

I am trying to use a progress bar as a life tracker for DND. I am using NumericUPDown boxes to control the life bar as one box is HP, a second is HP Max and the other is for the changes in HP.

I am having trouble with the HP NumericUpDown up clicker adding the Hp to be more than the Progress bar and it crashes the progream in debug. Can anyone help?

Code:

- HP is HP Numeric Up Down
- Health is Progress bar
- Max is Max HP Numeric Up Down

```
private void HP_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (HP.Value > Health.Maximum) ;
    Health.Maximum = (int)Max.Value;
```

Comment: Can you provide more information or explain it in different way(I'm having trouble understanding)? also what framework you are using? like is this unity, winForm, etc ?

Comment: Sorry its c# in viusal studio @yousif

So The progress bar is my life bar. I have numeric up down box as its health and max health. The max health is controled by the Max life number, Max progress bar =  max hp value. 

Then i have another numeric up down box thas control the progress part of the progress bar.

When i use the up button on the box and it goes over the max of progress bar it crashes.

Comment: @yousif 's question was about the UI tier you are using, whether it is for example `wpf` as opposed to `winforms` or `asp.net` or `uwp`

Comment: @StefanWuebbe @ yousif Winforms

Comment: _"Winforms"_ In that case your question would harvest more attention if you'd add the `winforms` Tag because many SO members are watching their favorite Tags preferentially

Comment: @Setefan cheers, not a coder so i dont know all this stuff. seems really hard to get help since i dont know these things.  wish more people were helpful in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I was overcomplicating it....
I was trying to do maths with the NumberUpDown stuff.

Didn't think for ages about just setting my maximum to be what I wanted the number to stop at.

```
            {
                HPNum.Maximum = MaxHPNUM.Value;

            }
```